# Develop a simple web service with a server http library in .net

Tags: .net, rest, web-services

I have to build a very simple web service to interact with a legacy application.

The idea is to build a "rest-ish" facade, pass everything to the legacy system, and spit-out json.

I was thinking about a simple and lightweight http library, not the whole mvc framework. Something like node's http library, that would allow me to access the request, response, headers, etc. url-rewriting would be pretty useful too.

I'm not familiar with .net libraries. Could I develop such a thing with the standard http library or should I go with a third party one?

Any code examples would be welcome

Comment: asp.net core might work or you could look at restsharp on git hub

Comment: restful services aren't all WebAPI over the MVC in .net, you can invoke a WCF service as restful.